# BeautifulSoup won't replace string

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

Function doesn't throw any error but strings stay the same after execute. It look like `replace_with` is doing nothing. So I checked types of var's and I thing this is the problem:

`<class 'str'> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

`fixed_text` is `str` and `blog_text` is `tag` type. I don't know how to resolve this problem.

```py
    def replace_urls(self):
        find_string_1 = '/blog/'
        find_string_2 = '/contakt/'
        replace_string_1 = 'blog.html'
        replace_string_2 = 'contact.html'

        exclude_dirs = ['media', 'static']

        for (root_path, dirs, files) in os.walk(f'{settings.BASE_DIR}/static/'):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]
            for file in files:
                get_file = os.path.join(root_path, file)
                f = open(get_file, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
                blog_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_1})
                contact_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_2})
                fixed_text = str(blog_text).replace(find_string_1, replace_string_1)
                fixed_text_2 = str(contact_text).replace(find_string_2, replace_string_2)
                blog_text.replace_with(fixed_text)
                contact_text.replace_with(fixed_text_2)
```

Comment: How did you check that the string wasn't altered? The file itself won't change.

Comment: When I ```print(fixed_text)``` string is changed, when ```print(blog_text)```is still the same. I also checked manual index.html. Under ```fixed_text``` and ```fixed_text_2``` are store new, wanted value. Only  ```replace_with_``` won't work. So how I be able to change and safe this new string in same .html file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems to work perfectly. However, from what I see, what you try to do is replace a whole `href` by another one. The simplest way to go is to do:

```
blog_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_1
```

This will change the element *inside* `soup`, so at the end you can do:

```
str(soup)
```

and see your changes. By doing `str(blog_text).replace`, you are working on a string which is detached from soup.

---

Minimal example:

```py
find_string_1 = '/blog/'
replace_string_1 = 'blog.html'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="/blog/">the text</a>', "lxml")

blog_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_1})
blog_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_1

print(str(soup))
```

result:

```
 '<html><body><a href="blog.html">the text</a></body></html>'
```

---

Edit: to write the changes back to a file:

```py
with open(some_file_name, 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. However now I don't know how to replace and save new string in .html file ? Not replace whole .html file, just put it where it has to be.

Comment: well, you need to replace the whole content I am afraid. See updated answer.

Comment: Now the problem is that the file (```f```) is already opened. So I'm trying just save and I see: ```f.write(soup.prettify('utf-8')) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes```

Comment: this is because you need to open it in byte mode, using the `"b"`. Why not open in read mode, close then open in write mode ? But these are other problems linked to file handling, not beautiful soup. Should we mark this question as solved ?